# jQuery Select an option value from a select element which is dynamically created after document is loaded

Tags: jquery

I have created a page for editing an entry in database. After entering the unique no. of the record, details is displayed in the form using jQuery post .First in the 'Cat' select box value is selected with the value returned from post request. Next, in the  a select box 'abcd' is dynamically loaded depending on value in the 'cat' select box. Now I want to select one option value from this which matches the 'type' value returned by post request.  But this is not working. In the case of 'Cat' select box, it is created in html and loaded with document load, but in 'abcd' it is populated using another jquery post request. How to accomplish selecting a value from this?
-----html in the page where form elements are created------

```
<form id="request_search" name="request_search" >
<fieldset class="request_fs">

<br/>
USIN:  <input type="text" name="usin" id="usin" onblur="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()"/>

<input id="Submit" name="Submit" type="Submit" value="Get Data" />
</fieldset>
    </form>

    <div id="edit_form">
   <form id="sampleentry" name="sampleentry" >
   <fieldset>
  <legend>Sample Data Entry</legend>
  <label for="loc">Location</label>

     <select name="loc" id="loc"><option value="">-----Select Location----</option>
     <?php 
     $db=mysql_select_db($database_hari,$hari) or die("could not connect");
$secsql= "SELECT location, site FROM villages ORDER BY location";
  $result_sec=@mysql_query($secsql) or die(mysql_error());

                while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result_sec))
                        { echo"<option value='".$row2['site']."-".$row2['location']."'>".$row2['location']."</option>";}

    ?>
     </select>
     <br />
     <br />
  <label for="cat">Category</label>
  <select name="cat" id="cat">
   <option value="">--Select Category--</option> 
   <option value="atmos">Atmospheric</option>
   <option value="aqua">Aquatic</option>
    <option value="fmd">Diet &amp;Animal Products</option>
   <option value="ter">Terrestrial</option>
   <option value="thy">Thyroid</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <br />
     <label for="abcd">Type</label>
     <select name="abcd" id="abcd" ><option value="">Select Category First</option></select>
     <br /><br />
     <span id="measurement"></span>


  <label for="start">Date</label>

  <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" value="<?php echo $dateindian; //echo date('d-m-Y');  ?>" /><input type="hidden" id="stddate" value="<?php echo $dateus; //echo date('d-m-Y');  ?>"/>

        <br />

        <span id="datepanel"> <br /><label for="start">To Date</label><input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2" value="<?php echo $dateindian; //echo date('d-m-Y');  ?>" /><input type="hidden" id="to_dt" value="<?php echo $dateus; //echo date('d-m-Y');  ?>"/><br /></span>
        <br />
        <!--<label for="sampleid">Ref. if An</label> <input name="sampleid" /> <br />-->
        <br />
   <label for="usin">USIN</label>
     <input name="usin" disabled="disabled" class="usin" />
     <br /><br />
     <label for="user">User</label>
       <input name="user" disabled="disabled" value= "<?php echo $_SESSION['EMPNO']; ?>" />
       <br /><br />
       <span class="chek">
       <input class="sam" name="samples" id="cs" type="checkbox" value="cs"/>Cs (RCA)
    <input class="sam" name="samples" id="sr" type="checkbox" value="sr"/>Sr (RCA)
    <input class="sam" name="samples" id="3h" type="checkbox" value="h3"/>3H
    <input class="sam" name="samples" id="gamma" type="checkbox" value="gamma"/>Gamma Spec
    <input class="sam" name="samples" id="alpha" type="checkbox" value="ga"/>Gross a
    <input class="sam" name="samples" id="beta" type="checkbox" value="gb"/>Gross ß
    <input class="sam" name="samples" id="iod" type="checkbox" value="iod"/>Iodine(by BCS)
    </span>
     <br /><br />
       <div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
```

-----Script for search and fill-----

```
jQuery('#request_search').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var usin=jQuery("#usin").val();

    jQuery.post("scripts/get_sample_register.php", {"usin":usin},  function(data) { 
        jQuery('#edit_form').show();

        var site=usin.substring(2,3);
        jQuery("#loc").val((site+'-'+data.location));
        jQuery("#cat").val(data.cat);


        var cate = jQuery('[name="cat"]').val();
        var temp = '';
        jQuery.post("insert_types.php", {"id": data.cat}, function(data){       
            jQuery('[name="abcd"]').html(data); 
        });
        jQuery("#abcd").val(data.type);     
    });
```

-----script for populating 'abcd'---------

```
<?php
require_once('Connections/hari.php');

$id=$_POST['id'];

$db=mysql_select_db($database_hari,$hari);
$sql= "select source from matrix where type='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo "<option value=''>---Select Type----</option>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<option value='".$row['source']."'>".$row['source']."</option>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery.post()` is asynchronous, but you're trying to populate the value before the callback that fills in the options runs. You need to do that in the second callback.

```
jQuery('#request_search').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var usin=jQuery("#usin").val();

    jQuery.post("scripts/get_sample_register.php", {"usin":usin},  function(data) { 
        jQuery('#edit_form').show();

        var site=usin.substring(2,3);
        jQuery("#loc").val((site+'-'+data.location));
        jQuery("#cat").val(data.cat);


        var cate = jQuery('[name="cat"]').val();
        var temp = '';
        jQuery.post("insert_types.php", {"id": data.cat}, function(data2){
            jQuery('#abcd').html(data2); 
            jQuery("#abcd").val(data.type);     
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: In the second call bcak data.type is undefined and it will not work

Comment: Yeah, need to use different variables for the parameters to each callback, so it doesn't shadow the variable.